# Argument of type x is not assignable to parameter of type '{ x: any; }'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I'm learning Angular and Typescript and getting this error. It seems like it is asking for me to clarify something with the type but I'm not sure exactly. I'm still pretty new at this so thanks for any help!

```
    src/app/shopping-list-new/shopping-edit/shopping-edit.component.ts:24:31 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Ingredient' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ Ingredient: any; }'.
  Property 'Ingredient' is missing in type 'Ingredient' but required in type '{ Ingredient: any; }'.
```

the code for the ingredients page looks like this

```
 export class Ingredient {

  constructor( public name: string, public amount: number) {

  }
}
```

and the code giving the error looks like this

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, EventEmitter, Output,  } from '@angular/core';
import { Ingredient } from '../../shared/ingredient.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-edit',
  templateUrl: './shopping-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-edit.component.css']
})
export class ShoppingEditComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('nameInput') nameInputRef: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('amountInput') amountInputRef: ElementRef;
  @Output() ingredientAdded = new EventEmitter<{Ingredient: any}>();


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onAddItem() {
    const ingName = this.nameInputRef.nativeElement.value;
    const ingAmount = this.amountInputRef.nativeElement.value;
    const newIngredient = new Ingredient(ingName, ingAmount);
    this.ingredientAdded.emit(newIngredient)
  }
}
```

Comment: `EventEmitter<{Ingredient: any}>()` this contains a dictionary of Ingredient & any. I think you want to replace it with `EventEmitter<Ingredient>()`

Answer (score 1):

Because here, `@Output() ingredientAdded = new EventEmitter<{Ingredient: any}>();`, You specify the emit type is `{Ingredient: any}`, as an object with `Ingredient` property, but it should object with `name` and `amount` properties.

Like this.

```
@Output() ingredientAdded = new EventEmitter<{name: string, amount: number}>();
```

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if that would be the case but just hadn't gotten that far!